# side channel attack on RSA implementation

Tags: rsa, side-channel-attack

What classes of side-channel attacks are applicable to RSA implementation and what is the efficiency rate ?

Comment: Actually, you don't have a side channel attack on "RSA" (or any crypto primitive); you have a side channel attack on an *implementation* of RSA.  Some implementations will be vulnerable to a variety of side channel attacks; others will be far more resistant (the hard-core side channel guys will say nothing is totally immune...)

Comment: Other relevant questions: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59334 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25163 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One type of side channel attacks on RSA is timing attack. It explots the timing variability of operation implementation. To secure against RSA timing attack, constant-time operations are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find out there one of "Paul Carl Kocher" development was [Timing Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack), that can break implementations of RSA, a timing attack is a side channel attack that attacker attempts to compromise a cryptosystem by analyzing the time taken to execute cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: Actually, Paul's work was far more focused on various power side channel attacks (for one, those give far more information to the attacker than a simple timing measurement).